# Python change hex string to hex int

Tags: python, hex

I'm struggling to find how I can change a hex string,`"0x44"`,to a hex int,`0x44`.

I've done a lot of searches but can't find any solutions.

There is probably a simple solution I'm missing.

Comment: Where do you need this? Is there a function which takes hex as argument?

Comment: Yes in `ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(hex_int,0,2,0)` im trying to simulate a keypress by using the virtual key code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to get a hex int. If you type in the python interpreter

```
0x10 == 16
```

it returns true. If the function takes an int (or hex int)
you can just convert it to an int.

use

```
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(int("0xdeadbeef",0),0,2,0)
```

and replace "0xdeadbeef" with the string of the key you want to press.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but anyway... there is no need to write `int("0xdeadbeef",0)`, because you can simply write `0xdeadbeef` instead. It is the same thing, as you explained yourself above.

Comment: @zvone I suppose he gets the hex from some input function which returns the string, I don't know why someone would ask this if not, but you might be right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `int` constructor with 16 as the second argument to specify the base of 16:

```
int('0x44', 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between common int and hex int:

```
>>> n = 68
>>> n
68
>>> n = 0x44
>>> n
68
```

So you can convert your string to int like this:

```
>>> s = "0x44"
>>> n = int(s, 16)
>>> n
68
```